# Windows Desktop app layout gets destroyed on other PC or server

Tags: c#, windows, layout

Hope anyone can help.
I developed a desktop app on a Windows 10 pc with Visual studio 2022.
Set .NET 6.0 as the framework and created a windows Forms app.

Build the app and tested it on the developer pc.
Worked fine.

Now transfered it to another W10 and Server2019 system.
On both systems i get the message i need to install the .net6 Desktop runtime with a link.
I installed it, rebooted the systems.
And when i run the forms application my complete layout is destroyed.
The app is running, and when i click the buttons, the actions get performed, but all layout and text is gone.
(see attached image)
[screenshots of both systems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRM09.jpg)
Can anyone think of a solution?

I tryed a fresh install of windows 10 and server 2019.
Tryed installing the full SDK instead of only the runtime

Comment: Add the code of the layout

Comment: From your image it looks like you are using two different executable's. On the Dev Environment you have different Window name (that you have blurred out) than on prod (Form 1).

Comment: Please check the information about the screen scale settings of both systems and add it to the question. WinForms is very dpi-dependent  and you may need to make a lot of adjustments and fixes to get it to work the same way at different dpi.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the answers.
In the end i found the answer.
I was using 2 language resources i did not need, but were destroying my interface.
the aa-DJ and NL-nl resources (.resx). As i understand especially aa-DJ does not seem to be supported in the W10 and Server2019 systems by default.
After removing these resources, it was oke again.